# Blacklist old token on reauthenticate with Laravel JWT

Tags: api, laravel, laravel-5, jwt

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and [tymondesigns/jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth).

Is it possible to blacklist old token if user logged in again without logout? I'm curious about the security of old token.

Any suggestion on how to improve the "always logged in" on mobile device as I am currently use Laravel as the API.

My current configuration is: ttl = 1 hour & refresh_ttl = 2 weeks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually @Jeff answer may solve the problem. I need to use `jwt.refresh` middleware.

My JWT blacklist not working because I'm using `array` as the `CACHE_DRIVER`

I have tested with revert it back to `file` as the `CACHE_DRIVER` and `jwt.refresh` is works, old token is blacklisted as it should be.

I marking this as the answer. Thank you, Jeff.

Comment: I have changed CACHE_DRIVER value as file and now Login and Logout is working fine. But for other APIs It returns this error.

"BadMethodCallException in Repository.php line 367:
This cache store does not support tagging."

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `jwt.refresh` middleware, which sends back a new token as a header in response.  If you have the blacklist enabled, the old token will be immediately blacklisted.  Just include `jwt.refresh` on your login route, and then make sure to capture the response header and update your local key. Then you can make your `ttl` and `refresh_ttl` unlimited (ie. `60*60*24*365*10`)

Comment: I have added `jwt.refresh` and I can see the token is being refresh on each request but the old token is not blacklisted. 

I checked on my jwt config file, the blacklist is already enabled. Any idea?

Comment: Hmm have you got a grace period enabled maybe? `'blacklist_grace_period' =>  0,`

Comment: Still can't make it blacklist the old token. Still no idea why and how to solve this. Actually, I'm using [SampleApi](https://github.com/zulfajuniadi/sampleapi) for this project.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table to store token at the first login of the user.

When that user logins again, you get the old token (from your table), then blacklist the old one, update the table with the new one which generate right after the login.